# Which version works properly with Solidity and Truffle?

Tags: truffle

The Solidity version 0.5.0 works well with Remix online software.
When you try to use that code in Visual Studio Code it creates an error, and there is not output after truffle compile,truffle migrate.

Truffle version:
  Truffle v5.0.7 (core: 5.0.7)
  Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
  Node v8.15.0

Comment: Please add a piece of code that produces the error and also the exact error itself.

Comment: After doing compile and error nothing is being printed

Comment: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard                       Entire Code is being written from this link which works completely fine with remix but in Viusal studio code when i do truffle compile no output found and even build/contracts is not developed